# How to chain tasks in celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I want to be able to chain tasks in celery so that the second tasks only exec after the first task has completed.

In the example below i have declared 2 tasks. `hello()` and `world()`. I want `world()` to execute only after `hello()` has completed.

**tasks.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from time import sleep


CELERY_BROKER = "pyamqp://guest@localhost//"

app = Celery('tasks', broker=CELERY_BROKER)


@app.task
def hello():
    sleep(2)  # simulate slow computation
    return "Hello"
@app.task
def world():
    sleep(2)  # simulate slow computation
    return "World"
```

**api.py**

```
from celery import chain
res = chain(hello.delay(), world.delay())
print(res)
```

This throws the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'AsyncResult' and
>   'AsyncResult'

Comment: When you chain two tasks and the first one returns a value, the second task should accept an argument which is the returned value of the first task. In other words, try declaring `def world(arg_result_of_hello)` instead of `def world()`.

Comment: If you want the result of the first task not to be passed as an argument to the second one, use `chain(hello.si(), world.si()).delay()`.

Answer (score -1):

Read about the Chain primitive of the Celery Canvas (workflow). I recommend reading the whole [Canvas: Designing Work-flows](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) section. Naturally, it talks, among other things, how to build [task chains](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) like you described.